# 98% CPU load when searching for updates (applydeltarpm)

Tags: linux, opensuse, high-cpu-usage

I'm running openSUSE 13.1 on my laptop and every time the system starts looking for updates, the fan goes crazy and the CPU load gets to over 90%. Using `top`, I discovered that the process `applydeltarpm` causes the load. Killing the process won't help since it restarts just a few seconds later. Moments later, the update notification of GNOME pops up and lets me install the new packages. After that, the CPU goes back to normal.

The laptop's a Sony Vaio S with an Intel i7 (Ivy Bridge), so performance shouldn't be the issue.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applydeltarpm` is a process internal to yum, which is OpenSUSE's package manager on top of RPM (also Fedora's and other RPM based distros).

The job of applydeltarpm is to reduce network load:

Instead of downloading the full RPM files from the repositories, special Delta-RPM files (`.drpm`) may be available, that are just a fragment of the download size.
In order to construct the real rpm file to be installed by RPM, applydeltarpm takes the old cached rpm in your filesystem and applies the delta-rpm on top of it. This process is CPU-intensive, and that's why you have a high load during that phase.

If you have a broadband connection and tiny batteries and/or you would rather consume bandwidth than CPU, then you can adjust yum's behaviour to when to download delta-rpms.

Depending on your Package Manager, you'll have to edit its configuration file.

In OpenSUSE, assuming you're using **zypper**:

There's a configuration option in `/etc/zypp/zypp.conf` called `download.use_deltarpm` which can be set to false. (Taken from [[1](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/yum.conf.5@yum.html)])

In Fedora, or assuming you're using **yum**:

There's a configuration option in `/etc/yum.conf` (see [`yum.conf(5)`](http://smithfarm-thebrain.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/opensuse-tell-zypper-to-not-do-delta-rpm.html)) called `deltarpm_percentage` that adjust how smaller has the delta-rpm to be to download it instead of the full rpm.

Comment: Since openSUSE uses zypper, I modified /etc/zypp/zypp.conf. I'll see how that's gonna work out for me. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, my fault; in Fedora Yum is the one, I'll update the answer.